# Why does casting a large prime integer using GMP's mpz_class result in a different number?

Tags: c++, casting, user-input, gmp

Quite simply, I have passed a large string as an input to GMP's mpz_class constructor, and the value is a different integer. These values were acquired through vs code's debugger.

From the main file:

`User john(1024, "340282366920938463463370103832140841039", "340282366920938463463370103832140841051", 17);`

The User constructor:

```
User::User(const int k, std::string p, std::string q, const int e) 
{
  this->m_k = k;
  this->m_p = mpz_class(p);
  this->m_q = mpz_class(q); 
  this->m_e = e;
  this->m_N = this->m_p*this->m_q;
  this->m_phi = (this->m_p - 1)*(this->m_q - 1);
}
```

Expected `m_p` value: `340282366920938463463370103832140841039`
Actual: `18442240474082181199`

Expected `m_q` value: `340282366920938463463370103832140841051`
Actual: `18442240474082181211`

It seems the difference between both numbers is still 12 but they are not the expected values. It should be mentioned that `k` and `e` are both set correctly.

It gets worse with this case.

```
User monica(k, 
        "79769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536000572708014448059344998673038813914022686832575861451235712608115812630507553330258219736187415555294488994451070856629343158126535469257597644947476477135408478542176849830316880553240227849994894682804453799",
        "79769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536000572708014448059344998673038813914022686832575861451235712608115812630507553330258219736187415555294488994451070856629343158126535469257597644947476477135408478542176849830316880553240227849994894682804454189", 
65537);
```

In this case `m_p == 423` and `m_q == 813` which is super far off!

Am I making a simple mistake? Thanks for helping!

Edit: Adding an minimal reproducible example.

```
std::string pp = "79769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536000572708014448059344998673038813914022686832575861451235712608115812630507553330258219736187415555294488994451070856629343158126535469257597644947476477135408478542176849830316880553240227849994894682804453799";

mpz_class p(pp);

std::cout << p << '\n';
```

Printing it out gives the original number but vscode shows some sort of compacted value. I guess the actual issue is somewhere else in the code. But why does VSCode display the large number like this?

Comment: You could simply put together a simple `main` program instead of having to go through class code.  What happens if you simply did those calculations on hard-coded values, and without involving `User`?   In other words a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Please provide class/struct User declaration.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a vscode thing because printing out the mpz_class results in the original number but in the debugger, I get a weird value.

I still don't know why vscode does this (presumably something to do with the size of the input).